# Why are we using 'are' for plural?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number, language-evolution

For example: He is eating.They are eating.

Why we won't say "They is eating". I think 'are' is not communicating anything additional.Why such a grammatical rule evolved?

Comment: In English, and many other languages, verbs are inflected (conjugated) to agree with the subject; grammatical number (plurality) is one of the most common inflections (linguistically speaking). In other words, it would be an anomaly if "be" *weren't* inflected for number, because every other verb is! I think more what you're struggling with is that "be" is an *irregular* verb: it conjugates weirdly. Perhaps ironically, but on a little reflection, unsurprisingly, it is exactly because "be" is so common and well-used that it is irregular. In other words: ***them's the breaks***, sorry.

Comment: Perhaps you should ask on linguistics.stackexchange.com why every human language is very *very* redundant. That's an interesting question. I have several suspicions for the reasons, but I'm not an expert.

Comment: The reason we don’t say “they is eating” (except in dialects where that is exactly what they do say) is that that’s not how the language works. There is no ‘why’ about it. Every language has lots of complications that are unnecessary, as Armen points out. That’s just the way it is. Based on your location, I would guess that your native language is Malayalam; in which case, I might just as well ask you why there’s a difference between മാണുഷൃൺ _maṇuṣyaṇ_ (nominative), മണുഷൃണെ _maṇuṣyaṇe_ (accusative), and മണുഷൃണു _maṇuṣyaṇu_ (dative), when you can just use one with prepositions, like English.

Comment: (Sorry if I’m butchering your language—I don’t know any Malayalam myself, I’m just going by Wikipedia.)

Comment: some languages conjugate verbs based on gender too. (e.g. Hindi ) it all depends on the language. Some don't conjugate at all ( Chinese ? ) and you need to infer more. Some programmers like C#, some like JavaScript. Don't ask why, just appreciate!

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Yes, that's true. I was just asking why such patterns were used!. But I didn't get why I am downvoted

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Also, In malayalam context that usage is required. The direct translation for "Raman killed Ravanan" is "രാമൻ (Raman) രാവണനെ (Ravana(ne)) കൊന്നു  (killed)." If നെ is not used, it will be like "Raman Ravanan Killed"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So we can tell whether there is more than one sheep eating when someone says "The sheep are eating".

Answer (score -2):

In Latin the present tense had six different forms

- sum es est - sumus estis sunt (am are is - are are are)

Why six forms? Latin didn't need special personal pronouns in connection with these verb forms as these pronouns were hidden in the endings. In su-mus we may suppose the pronoun nos (we). In es-tis we may  suppose a plural form of tu (you, singular).
es was probably something like *es-tu (tu you singular) but it was dropped altogether; in the corresponding perfect endings -vis-ti and -vis-tis these prounoun forms can be seen better. I suppose that est and sunt were mere participles. Perhaps pronouns were suffixed but they have vanished.

French still has six forms:

- je suis tu es il est - nous sommes vous êtes ils sont

French uses personal pronouns and could do with one single form but the different forms are still used, obviously they are practical.

German has only five forms:

- ich bin du bist er ist - wir sind ihr seid sie sind

English only three:

- I am you are he is - we/you/they are

So we see even though we use personal pronouns and one verb form would suffice the historical system is still in use even if it is reduced.

Added:

The Danish system is the simplest, it has for all three persons in sg and pl only one form.

- jeg/du/han er - vi/I/de er

In Old English the form for "are" was earun (Mercian) and aron (Norththumbrian). Influence of Old Norse. So one can say that the English plural form "are" for all three persons is influenced by Scandinavian.

Comment: Your presumptions about pre-Latin forms are not backed up by anything in any language whatsoever. There was never a 2sg ending _-tu_ anywhere, nor were _est_ and _sunt_ ever participles (even though the old participle would probably have yielded _sunt_ in the neuter singular, had it not been lost in Latin). The verbal endings are probably at least _related_ to the pronouns, but at a pre-Proto-Indo-European, possibly even pre-Proto-Indo-Uralic stage so early that we can only make the vaguest of speculations.

Comment: As I indicated it is an hypothesis. The present participle of esse would be essens/essent-tis. But it is not there. The forms sint and sunt may have derived from this participle an est may have derived from essent- as well. I don't look into (pre)proto-IE, I look only at Latin.

Comment: That’s exactly the problem—you can’t just look at one language and make reconstructions from that if it clashes with all other related languages. And as always, you assume that various sounds can just change or come and go at random, which is not how language works.

Comment: If you compare corresponding forms as Latin sint and sunt or sit and est one can see that inflexional morphems are not subject to normal historical sound change but behave to the necessities to create a conjugation system, and in this case an i of sint can become an u of sunt and a sis can become an es. By the way, how do you explain ti in amavisti and tis in amavistis?

Comment: You can see no such thing! If you compare only those forms (which makes no sense), you can only see that they belong to a highly irregular verb, and that the personal markers are _-t_ for 3sg and _-nt_ for 3pl. Nothing else. If you compare the full paradigms _sum/es/est/sumus/estis/sunt_ on the one hand and _sim/sīs/sit/sīmus/sītis/sint_ on the other, you can see that the subjunctive is far more regular than the indicative and is marked by the vowel _-i-_, whereas the indicative is marked by the absence of a vowel in some cases and an _-u-_ in others. There is _nothing_ there to [cont’d-->]

Comment: [-->cont’d] suggest that the _i_ of _sint_ has ‘become’ the _u_ of _sunt_. They’re different forms with different meanings, and one doesn’t ‘come’ from the other. If you compare with the same verb in other, related languages, you can see that the indicative is characterised by no vowel between stem and endings, while the subjunctive is characterised by a vowel _-e-_ or _-i-_ (long or short). The _-tī-_ in _-istī_ (note: that’s a long _ī_, unlike in the stem _tu-_) was in the earliest Latin texts written _-tei_, just like _-ī_ in 1sg was _-ei_; the 2pl was _-ite_, which was quite [cont’d-->]

Comment: [-->cont’d] early on reshaped to _-istis_ by taking the 2sg form and just adding a pluralising _-s_ to make it end in _-tis_ like all the other (non-imperative) forms in 2pl.

Comment: @rogermue I think you should do some reading about Indo-European historical linguistics before inventing such an unfounded and preposterous theory. The present tense of Latin sum has exact parallels in Sanskrit, Greek etc.

Comment: I see that all forms can be developed from a  participle form *essent- which can develop sint and sunt, est and sit , and with m from mea persona sim and sum, and with nos /nostrae personae/nostri simus and sumus and with tui/tuos sitis and estis. But as I said it is a hypothesis.